# Fill an existing form with an object of angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

## I have a table in angularjs named List.
    I Have a form with input in my html.
    I want to fill the value of my input with this table when i click on edit button . I don't know how i can select the value of input in angularjs .
Exemple with jquery : $('#name').val(); ##

### HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "employe" ng-controller="FormController as FormCtrl">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>List of employe</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width , initial-scale=0 ,shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./files/code.js"></script>

</head>

<body  ng-controller = "ListCtrl" >


<main>
    <div >

      <input type="button" value="Add new employee" ng-click="FormCtrl.setShow(2)">

      <form class="form-horizontal" name="infoForm" ng-submit="addEmployee()" ng-show="FormCtrl.isShow(2)" ng-hide="FormCtrl.isShow(1)" novalidate >
        <!--{{newemployee}}-->

         <h2>Add/Edit employee</h2>
         <!-- NOM -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <input type="texte" ng-model="newemployee.name" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- AGE -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Age</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
```

> Here my ng-change

```
              <input type="number" ng-change="change()" ng-model="newemployee.age" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- NICKNAME -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nickname" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nickname</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <input type="texte" ng-model="newemployee.nickname" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- EMPLOYEE -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employee" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Employee</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
             <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="newemployee.job" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Yes" value="yes">Yes
             </label>
             <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="newemployee.job" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="No" value="no" >No
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- JOB -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="job" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Job</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <select ng-model="newemployee.job" class="form-control">
                <option>Founder</option>
                <option>Market chef</option>
                <option>Stage</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- ANNEE -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="years" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Years</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <input type="number" ng-model="newemployee.years" class="form-control" ng-required="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- BUTTON -->
          <div class="center">

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Validate</button>

              <input type="button" value="Close" class="btn btn-default btn-warning" ng-click="FormCtrl.setShow(1) && reset()">

          </div>
    </form>
</div>
  <!-- TABLE -->
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Name (Job title)</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Nickname</td>
        <td>Years</td>
        <td>Employee</td>
        <td>Actions</td>
      </tr>
    </thead> 

   <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employeeList in list">
            <td>{{employeeList.name}} <span>{{employeeList.job}}</span></td>
            <td>{{employeeList.age }}</td>
            <td>{{employeeList.nickname }}</td>
            <td>{{employeeList.years }}</td>
            <td>{{employeeList.salarie }}</td>
            <td>
```

> Bouton EDIT + fonction setEditTrue pour ng-change

```
                <input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="FormCtrl.setShow(2) && ListCtrl.setEdit(true) && ListCtrl.setTable(employeeList)" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">

                <input type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="deleteEmployee(employeeList)" class="btn btn-default btn-danger">

            </td>      
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>


</main>
```

### Angularjs code

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('employe', []);

  app.controller("FormController", function () {
  this.Edit = 1;

  this.isShow = function(checkEdit){
    return this.Edit == checkEdit;
  };

  this.setShow = function(setShow){
    return this.Edit = setShow ;

  };

  console.log(this.Edit);
 });

 app.controller("ListCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.newemployee = {};  

    $scope.addEmployee = function(){

        $scope.list.push({

          name: $scope.newemployee.name,
          age : parseInt($scope.newemployee.age),
          nickname : $scope.newemployee.nickname,
          job : $scope.newemployee.job ,
          years : parseInt($scope.newemployee.years),
          salarie : $scope.newemployee.job                 

       });
       console.log($scope.list); 

       $scope.newemployee.name = "";
       $scope.newemployee.age = "";
       $scope.newemployee.nickname = "";
       $scope.newemployee.job = ""; 
       $scope.newemployee.years = "";
       $scope.newemployee.job = "";    
    };
    console.log($scope.list);  

    $scope.deleteEmployee = function(employeeList){
      var removeEmployee = $scope.list.indexOf(employeeList);
      $scope.list.splice(removeEmployee, 1);
    }

    $scope.reset = function(){
      $scope.newemployee.name = "";
      $scope.newemployee.age = "";
      $scope.newemployee.nickname = "";
      $scope.newemployee.job = ""; 
      $scope.newemployee.years = "";
      $scope.newemployee.job = ""; 

    };
    var edit = false;
    $scope.setTrue = function(set){
     edit = set;
    }

    var empList = {};
    $scope.setEmplist = function(thisEmp){

      return empList = thisEmp;

    }
    $scope.change = function(empList) {
     if(edit == true){
       $scope.newemployee.name = empList.name;
      }
   };

  }]);


})();
```

Comment: I cannot make any cheese of your question

Comment: if only you want to fill value in fields that can be done easily by providing value to your model for example one of you model is ng-model="newemployee.age" to fill this field give value $scope.newemployee.age =5

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is incorrect. If you wish to have an editable table, you must have some input controls in each of the `<td>` of your table. The content within each td should be a text block & an input control. Clicking on edit will toggle the visibility of the input control and text block. This has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: Nice Idea but it's an exercise i must use the form for edit and add people in my td . thanks :')

Comment: Why don't you have a radio button field option in your table, which determines which row is being edited. Once, the particular row is selected, you should autopopulate the input fields of the form with the selected row's values. You can easily get the row index by using `$index` of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Yes i have it , i've just try the jquery code , it's worked  didn't know i could use jquery with angularjs(first time use) thanks next job replace the existing data by the new one ^^

Comment: What you could try is , put an ng-change on the input elements. On the change event, check if the edit mode is set to true. If so, update the selected row(identify using `$index`) of the `$scope.list` object. Your table should get updated as well. Please mark as answer if this helped.

Comment: i don't see how to use it :c

Comment: var edit = false;
    $scope.setTrue = function(set){
        edit = set;
    }
    $scope.change = function(employeeList) {
        if(edit == true){
          $scope.newemployee.name = employeeList.name;
        }
     };

Comment: I miss click , i tryied this : `var edit = false;
    $scope.setTrue = function(set){
        edit = set;
    }
    $scope.change = function(employeeList) {
        if(edit == true){
          $scope.newemployee.name = employeeList.name;
        }
     };`

Comment: You need to iterate through employeeList.

Comment: I've modified my code  on edit button , and angularjs (last both fonction) .